# TomCat Servlet execution java.lang.StackOverflowError exception

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-fop, xalan

I am randomly getting the following error on first call to Apache TomCat 8.5.51 after the service restart. The error automatically goes away after sometime which makes it very hard to debug.

What could be the reason for it?

Error Log:

```
    27-Jul-2021 13:40:44.965 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@75f16954')
    27-Jul-2021 13:41:03.686 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Cocoon] in context with path [/cocoon-2.1.11] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
        java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at org.apache.xml.utils.SuballocatedIntVector.<init>(SuballocatedIntVector.java:115)
            at org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBase.<init>(DTMDefaultBase.java:207)
            at org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBaseTraversers.<init>(DTMDefaultBaseTraversers.java:90)
            at org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBaseIterators.<init>(DTMDefaultBaseIterators.java:85)
            at org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.sax2dtm.SAX2DTM.<init>(SAX2DTM.java:253)
            at org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.sax2dtm.SAX2DTM.<init>(SAX2DTM.java:224)
            at org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.sax2dtm.SAX2RTFDTM.<init>(SAX2RTFDTM.java:126)
            at org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault.getDTM(DTMManagerDefault.java:307)
            at org.apache.xpath.XPathContext.getRTFDTM(XPathContext.java:1258)
            at org.apache.xpath.XPathContext.pushRTFContext(XPathContext.java:1275)
            at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:386)
            at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
            at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
            at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
            at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:248)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:141)
    org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
    org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)
```

Comment: [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) says it's mainly caused by a recursion issue. Since the error is thrown inside xalan code and there's no indication of recursion in the stack trace, the issue could be an [undersized](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-how-to-solve-stackoverflowerror/) `-Xss` passed to the JVM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had to truncate the stack trace as it was too long. I will update the answer with full stack trace.

Comment: Now the recursion can be seen in these repeating lines: `org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400) org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394)`. Something in the xml estructure might be causing it. the complete stack trace could have more info.

Comment: Thank you. I am using it for XSLT transformation. There is a string replace function which seems to cause this. If I remove it then I do not get this error. However, the thing I dont understand is.. it occurs first time (or randomly) and starts working on its own. What could be the reason for it?

Comment: The document size I guess. Might depend on the number of replacements done

Comment: hmm.. it works with the same document :s I guess I am a lot closer than having no clue about it. Is there anyway to configure xss at TomCat 8.5 server level? (I am a .Net developer - never used it before).

Comment: Yes, it's possible to configure that. Are you able to reproduce at will?

Comment: Yes, I am able to reproduce it after including the string replace function and restarting the TomCat server. The very first request to the string replace function ends up in this error. If I try some other request and go back to the original request then it starts working too.

Comment: so it fails only the first time with thw same exact request? Look at catalina logs

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: Try increasing Xss

Comment: I checked the catalina log but nothing in there. I will try to increate the XSS at TomCat server level. Thanks for your help.

Comment: np :-) Let me know how it went please. I can then add an answer to summarize the issue.

Comment: The root cause of the issue was recursion in the stack trace, I managed to fix it. Thanks for your help. You can summarize it in an answer,

Comment: Glad it worked. Let me know if something is missing in the summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*java.lang.StackOverflowError* according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html)

> Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply.

From the stack trace, the recursion can be seen in lines below. `ElemTemplate.execute` calls `TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates` which in turns calls the former thus establishing the recursion:

```
org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:394).
```

Something in the xml estructure or the code parsing it might be causing the `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.
Could be worth to check also [`-Xss` jvm setting](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-how-to-solve-stackoverflowerror/).